Distinguish each alert, but they all come out red
I want to mark Critical Alert in red, Warning Alert in orange, and Normal Alert in green. But when all three alerts are sent at the same time, they all come out in red. I want each Slack Alert notification color to be distinguished. By the way, they all come out in red as shown in the picture below.
Here is my Grafana Alert Template.
{{ define "slack_title" }}
  {{ if gt (len .Alerts.Firing) 0 }}
   {{ len .Alerts.Firing }} alert(s) firing
  {{ end }}
  {{ if gt (len .Alerts.Resolved) 0 }}
  ✅ {{ len .Alerts.Resolved }} alert(s) resolved
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}

{{ define "slack_message" }}
  {{ if gt (len .Alerts.Firing) 0 }}
    {{ range .Alerts.Firing }} {{ template "slack_alert_firing" .}} {{ end }} {{ end }}
  {{ if gt (len .Alerts.Resolved) 0 }}
    {{ range .Alerts.Resolved }} {{ template "slack_alert_resolved" .}} {{ end }} {{ end }}
{{ end }}

{{/* alert */}}
{{ define "slack_alert_firing" }}
 Alert Fired
Cluster: {{ .Labels.Cluster }}
Instance: {{ reReplaceAll ":9100" "" .Labels.instance }}
Value: {{ .Annotations.Value }}
Node: {{ reReplaceAll "aks-" "" .Labels.nodename }}
Severity: {{ .Labels.severity }}
{{ end }}

{{ define "slack_alert_resolved" }}
✅ Alert Resolved
Cluster: {{ .Labels.Cluster }}
Instance: {{ reReplaceAll ":9100" "" .Labels.instance }}
Value: {{ .Annotations.Value }}
Node: {{ reReplaceAll "aks-" "" .Labels.nodename }}
Severity: Normal
{{ end }}

{{/* Color of Slack attachment (appears as line next to alert )*/}}
{{ define "slack.monzo.color" -}}
    {{ if eq .Status "firing" -}}
        {{ if eq .CommonLabels.severity "warning" -}}
            warning
        {{- else if eq .CommonLabels.severity "critical" -}}
            danger
        {{- else -}}
            #439FE0
        {{- end -}}
    {{ else -}}
    good
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}



Don't know why are they all red, but as I understand single message can have only one color. To have distinguished color for each alert you'll need to disable grouping with group_by: ['...']. But it will result in 4 messages in your example; make sure it's what you want

Hello. Thank you for your response, but I don't know what you mean by deactivating "group_by". What else is "receiver"? Can't you solve it with the Grafana Alert template alone? @markalex

idk if you were able to solve the issue, but my approach would be to use notification policies to fire different
by doing so, you would send several messages simultaneously, each of them with its corresponding color.
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/notifications/notification-policies/
